# $f(\epsilon_n) \to y$ for any sequence implies $f(\epsilon) \to y$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $f\colon A \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}$. Can I show that $f(\epsilon) \to y$ for $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ if I take an arbitrary sequence $(\epsilon_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $A$ with $\epsilon_n \downarrow 0$ for $n \to \infty $ and show that $f(\epsilon_n) \to y$ for $n \to \infty $?

Comment: No, showing it for a specific sequence isn’t sufficient. For example, consider $1/n$ and $sin(2pi/x)$. It evaluates to 0 at each point in the series even though it doesn’t have a limit near 0. You need to show it for every possible such sequence.

Comment: @Fred f is not assumed continuous.

Comment: @Eric Yes that's what I meant by arbitrary sequence. But then it is true if that's the case?

Comment: @Jacobiman Yes, this works. I discussed this in an answer ages ago, it's a fundamental relation between sequence convergence and the functional limit at a point (I'd called it the SFR, sequence-function relation). The idea is to contradict the definition $f(\epsilon) \not \to y$ then use specific values of failing $\delta$s to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this result is valid and in fact it corresponds to an alternative definition of limit of a function at a point, known as *Heine's* definition.